# My fonts work different on button and input tag

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

This question is pure for designers.
On my html page I call fonts in header like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=BioRhyme&display=swap">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fonts.css">
```

My fonts.css file look like this:

```
* {
    font-family: 'BioRhyme', serif;
}
```

But my fonts look different on `<button>` and on `<input>` is there a way to bypass that and make it look like rest of the page and how?

Comment: I think you should rather look into how to overwrite CSS files rather than loading different fonts.

Comment: I just wanna ask why did I get -2 on legit question? Why disaprove this question? Becouse you dont know answer or you get more points by doing that? Question is well formed...

Comment: Have you checked with the developer tools that the font used in button or input is indeed the font you want to use? Be careful of css being overwritten by another class. It is not a good practice, but for testing, you can place an !important in your css.

Comment: You could give more info. Like in which browsers are you testing it and which SO. Internet Explorer (up to version 10) has a bug with some fonts in inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If elements aren't using the font-family you've set it means they're being overridden by something, this could be another CSS file or a browser default.

Your [browser's dev tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools) can show you what styles are being applied to an element and which CSS file they come from.

You could also use the `!important` modifier to override other style sheets.

```
* {
    font-family: 'BioRhyme', serif !important;
}
```